# POST method to send RAW TEXT data and get HTML Response using Jquery AJAX Web Method and check with POSTMAN

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, postman, webmethod

I'm Trying to do a POST Request using RAW TEXT.

I want to send POST Request from POSTMAN like, in body Section I've selected RAW(from radio buttons) and Text(from drop-down) and pass below simple string.

```
01JAINAM120112356598
```

Now, when we click on send in Postman, Response must come in HTML string "01" on success and "00" on error.

[Type of Request & Response I Need] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET2cV.jpg   (In photo URL is of .php page, but I'll pass my asp.net c# page (.aspx)).

I need to use JQuery ajax code to pass request & get proper response.
Something like,

```
$.ajax({
           url: "RFID.aspx/saveRFIDData",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "text",
           success: function () {
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error")
            }
      });
```

But, when I call above URL as post method as same shown in Image above, my WebMethod in code behind is not called.

Instead, when I call same ajax call for JSON, my WebMethod is been called.
But, I don't want to pass JSON.

So, Can anyone help me to get it done with "dataType : text" & get HTML string response.

**Note : If someone didn't Understand my question. Do comment first, to be more clear rather than DEVOTE this question**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be "Unsupported Media Type" issue and status may be 415. Add supported media type, that might work.

Comment: I get 200 status with whole HTML Page in response. But my Web Method is not called.